# Android: Don't understand why canvas not draw my stored paths

Tags: android, xamarin, path, draw

I used the fingerpaint demo and modify it for multi touch. This part is all fine and the path get drawn as expected. Now, I need to stored these path into an ArrayList so when I swipe each View in viewpager I can keep the state and redrawn those path stored in memory.

This is my code to draw canvas.

```
        protected override void OnDraw (Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw (canvas);

        canvas.DrawBitmap (mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        if (Strokes != null && Strokes.Count > 0) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Strokes.Count; i++) {
                var path = (Path) Strokes[i].Path; 
                canvas.DrawPath (path, Strokes[i].Pen);
            }   
        }
    }
```

The part I passed the Stroke List :

```
viewPagerAdapter.InitializedView += (object sender, PreviewPagerViewEventArgs e) => {
            if (mPageData.Count <= e.Position)
                mPageData.Add (e.Data); 
            else {
                var view = (DrawableView) GetVisibleView (e.Position);
                view.Background = new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Blue);
                view.Strokes = (List<StrokeData>) mPageData [e.Position];
                view.Invalidate();
            }
        };
```

I placed a bullet point and the canvas.DrawPath did get through but the canvas still not get drawn

Comment: Have you got a link to the fingerpaint demo, you used?